# Include, Require a syntax error file

Tags: php, include, syntax-error, require

I would like to ask can I require/include a file that has syntax errors and if I cant, the require/include returns a value so that I know that the required/included file has syntax errors and cannot be required/included ?

file.php has syntax error

```
include('file.php')
if (not file.php included because of syntax)
   this
else
   that
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really wanted this type of functionality.

You could try using [nikics php parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) to see if you can successfully parse the file or not.

```
$code = file_get_contents('yourFile.php');

$parser = new PhpParser\Parser(new PhpParser\Lexer\Emulative);

try {
    $stmts = $parser->parse($code);
    // $stmts is an array of statement nodes
    // file can be successfully included!
} catch (PhpParser\Error $e) {
    // cannot parse file!
    echo 'Parse Error: ', $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In PHP 7, Parsing errors can be caught, which makes this probably the most robust, elegant, built-in solution:

```
<?php

function safe_require_once(string $fname) {
    try {
        require_once($fname);
    } catch( Throwable $e ) {
        //will throw a warning, continuing execution...
        trigger_error("safe_require_once() error '$e'", E_USER_WARNING);
    }
}

safe_require_once("./test1.php"); //file with parse or runtime errors
echo "COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY THO";
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use something ike this:

```
if((@include $filename) === false)
{
    // handle error
} else { //....}
```

the `@` is used to hide the error message

Comment: This will hide the errors of include itself. Op ask about syntax errors.

Comment: @Leggendario if that is the question then the question doesn't make sense. PHP doesn't check on such error before including. It first includes the file, then reads it (the other way around would be impossible, right?)

Comment: if the included file has syntax errors, execution is stopped, even with the error suppressor. nothing past the include will work.

Comment: @Ixer no one said that the question make sense eheh